# Smoothed CDF to calculate asymptotic normality

Tags: self-study, asymptotics, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

If we have the following estimator: $\hat{F_Z}(z)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N1\{Z_i\leq z\}$. The CDF of $Z$ is defined as $F_Z(z)=Pr(Z\leq z)$. $Z_1, ..., Z_N$ is i.i.d. data.

What would be the steps to show that $\hat{F}$ is consistent and asymptotically normal and to find the asymptotic variance at a given point $z$.

My thought was to get the pdf but apparently $\hat{F}$ is not very useful for estimating the PDF. That I don't understand why?

I am not sure but this is what I got so far:
$$\hat{F_Z}(z)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N1\{Z_i\leq z\}\xrightarrow{LLN}E[1(Z_i\leq z)]=Pr(Z\leq z)=F_Z(z)$$

$$\sqrt{N}(N^{-1}\sum 1(Z_i\leq z)-E[1(Z_i\leq z))\xrightarrow{CLT}N(0, Var(1(Z\leq z)))$$

The questions are related so I merged them together but if needed I can post a new one.

If we would consider now a random variable U independent of Z with CDF $F_U(\cdot)$,  and a symmetric PDF, and consider some $h > 0$. We now consider a different estimator $$\tilde{F}(z)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^NF_U[\frac{z-Z_i}{h}]$$ Is $\tilde{F}$ consistent for $F_Z$?

For this, I guess we would be using the nonparametric approach. Would we follow the same steps as with the previous one or is it a different thing?

Comment: You haven't assumed anything that would imply $Z$ has a density.  As far as the steps go, apply the Central Limit Theorem to $\hat F_Z.$

Comment: In addition, you can apply the law of large numbers directly to show consistency. All of this assumes you are interested in pointwise asymptotic results, rather than uniform asymptotic results.

Comment: I'm still unsure on how to proceed but can the idea be similar to this source: https://sites.stat.washington.edu/people/fanghan/teaching/STAT583/quantile.pdf ?

Comment: I've had a glance at the notes you've linked, and I don't think they quite get to the heart of the matter. Concerning uncertainties on how to apply the aforementioned results, can you see how or why when you fix $z \in \mathbb{R}$ at a particular value, you can view $\hat{F}_Z(z)$ as a sample mean, and $F_Z(z)$ as an expectation?

Comment: @microhaus to be honest no. I'm really not sure how to proceed with this question. I need maybe like the first step how to start so I can go from there because as of now, it's not making so much sense to me

Comment: Not a problem. I will post a hint in the answers. Perhaps that will nudge you in the right direction. If the hint doesn't get you anywhere, then just prompt and I will make appropriate edits.

Comment: The main elements look good to me. However, I would use $\overset{p}{\rightarrow}$ and $\overset{d}{\rightarrow}$ to denote convergence in probability and distribution respectively. You can simplify $\text{Var}(1\{Z_i \leq z \})$ further to get it in terms of $F_Z(z)$. And in your pointwise asymptotic normality statement you can write the rescaled difference between the sample mean and expectation in terms of $\hat{F}$ and $F$.

Comment: Yeah I see, I'll make those changes. But why isn't $\hat{F}$ is not very useful for estimating the PDF?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what that part of your question was getting at. My instinct for estimating a PDF without recourse to parametric methods would be to use a histogram or a kernel density estimator. But I don't rule out the possibility that you may be able to do that given a particular empirical CDF. Perhaps other members of the community might be able to assist on that front.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $z \in \mathbb{R}$ to be some value. Now for illustrative purposes, define corresponding i.i.d. random variables $Y_i = g(Z_i) = 1\{Z_i \leq z\}$. The following prompts should hopefully assist in getting to the solution you require.

Notice that $Y_i$ is a discrete random variable.

1. What values can $Y_i$ take? Do you know of any discrete distributions that appropriately describe $Y_i$? How this distribution parametrised?

2. What is the mean $\mathbb{E}[Y_i]$ and variance $\text{Var}[Y_i]$?

3. Can you express $\hat{F}_Z(z)$ and $F_Z(z)$ in terms of $Y_i$, or anything in question 2?

Comment: I updated on what I think the solution might be, but I'm not sure. Can you please check and let me know what you think?